# Does twitter notify other people who liked the same tweet?

Tags: twitter

I have recently liked a tweet from someone's likes (the tweet is by a third party). Does Twitter notify them that I liked it?

Answer (score 1):

No, Twitter does not notify other users who liked the same tweet that you liked it too. (It does notify the author of the tweet.)